# Meta-analysis in R: multiple effect sizes with unknown correlation

Tags: multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model, meta-analysis, effect-size

I'm working on a meta-analysis with multiple effect sizes reported in most studies. My effect sizes are SMD between two groups (health/ disease) and the reason there is multiple effect sizes per study is either due to measuring different proteins in one area, same protein in multiple areas or multiple proteins in multiple areas. All are based on the same groups of subjects within each study though.

I don't know what the correlation between different proteins or areas are, don't have enough data to calculate these and can't find anything in the literature.
So to work around that somehow I did multiple multilevel meta-analysis (using metafor) with different values for effect size correlation within studies. My results then range between an overall effect of 0.68 to 0.81.

However, now I'm stuck at how to determine which of these would be the most appropriate option?

It doesn't help that I'm not even sure there is any correlation between effect sizes because as far as the literature is concerned difference in one protein in disease doesn't mean there is any change in others and the same goes for differences in one protein in a certain area compared to a different area.

Comment: What is even the biological meaning of combining effect sizes from measurements of different proteins in different areas? I think you first need to understand the research question you are addressing before figuring out the appropriate statistical approach.

Comment: @BryanKrause I'm doing something similar to this https://academic.oup.com/schizophreniabulletin/article/46/2/374/5514551?login=true#199797969
but I also will be looking into the individual proteins and areas (where there are enough studies)

Comment: Thanks, that makes a bit more sense. It might be useful to edit some high level summary of the approach you're taking to your question (eg: concentrations of different proteins are used as a surrogate for synaptic density).

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems like if the surrogate is appropriate, the correlation of the ground truth (not necessarily the observations) should be ~1.